# Is it okay to update primary key field to shift a record to the top?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have scheduled content and new records shown based on primary id ordering. So I'm just updating the record to make it appear on top on the UI.

```
$nextId = getNextAvailableId("comment"); // returns Auto_increment of SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'comment'

mysqlQuery("update `comment` set status=1,comment_id=$nextId WHERE comment_id = '$comment_id' limit 1");
```

Is this structure okay?

Comment: Never put "logic" into the value of the primary key. What about other tables referencing your table? You will get problems with your foreign key constraints.

Comment: If you need business logic for sorting rows, you need a sort order column, an int or a date maybe. Otherwise you will get into exactly these difficulties

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm updating all tables who depend on each other's primary keys. I could use a date but will it not cause lack of performance?

Comment: Why would a date be slower? Plus: if you use a date or timestamp you don't need to update anything. There is no solution that is faster than *not* doing anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not a good idea.

Primary keys are used for two reasons: looking up records and to allow for foreign key references.

Updating your key will mess up any foreign key references so you should not do this.

Primary keys should in general not be used for ordering. Use a date or name field or something with actual meaning instead.

Comment: Mess up how? I'm updating all tables who depend on each other's primary keys. I could use a date but will it not cause lack of performance?